# Blocking operator==() at compile time

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, runtime-compilation

I have an ID-Record class and I want to block callers / users from using the operator== since it is ambiguous (user may want to compare only data field for equality).

Here's my class:

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>

class ID_Record
{
  public:
    bool operator==(const ID_Record& other) const
        {  throw std::bad_function_call(); }
    unsigned int id;  // Record ID used for database.
    std::string  value;
};
```

I would prefer to have `operator==()` "blocked" at compile time, so the compiler can catch it rather than at runtime.

The compiler should generate an error for this code:

```
ID_Record a(6, "Tree");
ID_Record b(3, "Platinum");
if (a == b) std::cout "Records are equal\n"; // This line should fail compilation.
```

I want to block cases of compiler generated functionality also.

Comment: Not declaring the operator at all is a pretty great compile time way to block it. Also the most code-gold-friendly.

Comment: The compiler doesn't automatically generate `==` without explicitly opting into it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since C++11, you can explicitly declare any class method/operator with [`= delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions) to prevent it from being callable, eg:

```
class ID_Record
{
  public:
    bool operator==(const ID_Record& other) const = delete;
    unsigned int id;  // Record ID used for database.
    std::string  value;
};
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/tz2kfv)

If code tries to invoke the deleted `operator==` in any way, the compile will fail with an error message, such as:

> error: use of deleted function ‘bool ID_Record::operator==(const ID_Record&) const’

On the other hand, if you simply omit the `operator==` completely, eg:

```cpp
class ID_Record
{
  public:
    unsigned int id;  // Record ID used for database.
    std::string  value;
};
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/xuGR4u)

Then you will *also* get a (different) compile error, such as:

> error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘ID_Record’ and ‘ID_Record’)

The compiler will not generate a default `operator==` for you, unless you explicitly ask for it [via `= default` in C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons) and later.

Comment: This works!  I'm getting the error message: `error C2280: 'bool MP_Records::Id_String::operator ==(const MP_Records::Id_String &) const': attempting to reference a deleted function`

Comment: @ThomasMatthews This is analogous to doing (for example) `void Foo() = delete;` though.  You wouldn't ever do that, so why explicitly delete `operator==`, which, as mentioned in the comments above, will not be generated by the compiler automatically (any more than `Foo` would) and is really just a regular old function with a funky name?  So just don't declare it at all and you're golden (unless perhaps you prefer the compiler error Remy's answer generates when you try to use it).

Comment: I have updated my answer to include omitting the operator completely.

Comment: For completeness, it would be worth mentioning that deleting `operator==` has a different effect from not declaring it. If you don't declare `operator==`, it's possible that some other `operator==` will get selected by overload resolution, if `ID_Record` is implicitly convertible to its argument types.